# Getting NullPointerException while developing simple Google map application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am new to Google maps of Android and I am developing simple Google map application using Android.(I am using Google map V2).

I referred this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614946/Android-google-map-api-v-setup

Also i tried to use MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment but still,
I am facing NullPointerException at line 24:

```
line 24:   googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

Where i did a mistake? Please suggest me changes in the code if any.

Following is the code of MainActivity where i am facing the exception.

```
package com.example.mymap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
   GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-33.796923, 150.922433);
    **googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);**
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("My Spot")
            .snippet("This is my spot!")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mymap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mymap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="My API Key"/>
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

**Layout File:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the log cat output:**

[image]

Comment: post your layout file..

Comment: At which line you got NPE?

Comment: @ Piyush : at line 24. i have written it in question..  googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

Comment: @ kalyan : i have edited my question..i have provided my layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:-

```
googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

Write this :-

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

Refer this [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/), It will help you a lot.

Comment: write this :- 

googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
```

to

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

And also change this

```
googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

to

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

Comment: @Rohit post your error and u try this into physical device

Comment: @Rohit after this changed you must built new apk again and uninstall the older

Comment: Please see the snippet i have posted which is the log cat content.(shows NullPointerException at line 24)

Comment: app is working on physical device... but not on emulator...So now, how can i execute it on emulator...and this proves that there is nothing wrong in written code... then why emulator is not able to run it and throwing an exception?? any idea ??

Comment: @Rohit u need to set up `google_play_lirary_lib` differently into your `Emulator`. but i give u advice never test into your `Emulator` this error came becoz emulator not finding `google_play_lirary_lib classes`

Comment: @ Simple Plan I have already installed this lib and attached to my app. (then Some thing must have gone wrong). I referred to the posted link and followed the same steps..So can you suggest or post a link which will work for me?

Comment: @Rohit i told you this becoz i faced the same issue in past.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Google Play Services installed on your testing device?
If not, getMap() returns null. 
If you test in on an emulator, only the emulators with Android version 4.2.2 and above have Google Play Services installed.

Comment: yes i have installed google play services.. I have installed both google play services and google play services for froyo